# Why int32_t faster then int64_t?

Tags: c++

Example code:

```
template<typename T>
inline void Solution() {
    T n = 0;
    T k = 0;
    T s = 1;
    while (k < 500) {
        n += s++;
        k = 2;
        T lim = n;
        for (T i = 2; i < lim; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                lim = n / i;
                k += 2;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << "index: " << s << std::endl;
    std::cout << "value: " << n << std::endl;
}
```

There is a difference between calculation time when i use int32_t and int64_t (more then 2x times). So, simple question is: "Why?"

```
Solution<int32_t> -> 0.35s on x32 build
Solution<int64_t> -> 0.75s on x32 build
```

Comment: Why not? What's your expected result?

Comment: are you on a 64-bit system?

Comment: Have you looked at the generated assembly code for the two versions?

Comment: In 64-bit mode, the only real difference is GCC's choice of registers. `rax` et al. for `int64_t` and `eax` et al. for `int32_t`, but the instructions produced are identical. In 32-bit mode, since there are no 64-bit registers available significantly more code is produced for `int64_t`.

Answer (score 2):

If `x32` build means that your platform is 32bit then results are expected as size of the machine word is 32 bits. What is `sizeof(void*)` on your platform?

If it 64-bit then it could mean that your while loop doesn't fit into the instructions cache line of your cpu.

Actually profiling tools like (gprof, cachegrind, stackgrind etc) will provide more correct answer than guessing here.

Answer (score 1):

Print out the assembly language, especially the division.

On a 32-bit platform, the 64-bit arithmetic may need to be performed in *double-word* style.  For example, with addition the lower 32-bit values are added first, then the higher 32-bits are added along with the carry from the first addition.  The assembly language will show this.

Also, unless your platform has division instructions, the division will be performed by software.  The 64-bit division will have more operations than the 32-bit, thus taking longer.

As others have said, check the instruction and data alignments for your machine.  The assembly language should show this.